# PPTP: Use LDAP or PAM as authentication backend

Tags: vpn, pptp, ldap, ppp

I'm using pptpd and pppd on a Debian linux host to provide VPN capabilities to mobile phones. I would like to use my OpenLDAP server for authentication and authorization purposes (instead of keeping users and cleartext passwords in `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets`). Is that possible?

I have normal unix login working via libpam-ldap, does that help?

I've read some stuff about using FreeRADIUS in between pppd and OpenLDAP, but it sounds to me like overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSCHAPv2 authentication requires the server to have cleartext passwords. I dont't think you can get around that if your clients are mobile phones - you need certificates for the other strong authentication methods.

I had once a setup pptpd->FreeRADIUS->MySQL running. The pppd has no direct ldap plugin AFAIK, so you absolutely need to employ RADIUS in between. And you need cleartext passwords somewhere - I would not feel that good storing them in LDAP, but it should be possible.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it! I might look into L2TP instead then.